# Save more values to one key and still use hash.value?(['something'])

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I need to save more values with the same key into a hash in Ruby. But I still want to be able to find them with `.value?`.

If I save array to hash, I can't find a single value.

For example, if I have array `['something', 'something2']` which I have to save to index 1 in `hash`. Then `hash.value?(['something'])` returns false. I need it to return true. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

One of possible ways:

```
hash.values.flatten.include?('something')
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on what @nsave said, you can either do:

```
hash.values.flatten.include?('something')
```

Or look up by key.  That may be more straightforward and what you are looking for.  You didn't say what key you are using, but say you are using `:things`:

```
hash[:things] = ['something', 'something2']
#=> ["something", "something2"]    

hash[:things].include? 'something'
#=> true
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you checking to see if the hash contains the string `'something'` somewhere in its values OR are you checking if the hash contains a value of an array containing one string element 'something', ie `['something']`?  If the first, use something like `hash.values.flatten.include?("something")`.  Otherwise, `hash.value?(['something'])` is correctly returning `false` as the hash does not have a value of `["something"]`

Comment: Do no ask for clarification in an answer.  Ask for clarification in comments and post answers as an answer.